# What are trips on Facebook's Timeline map page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Go to a Facebook Timeline profile, click on the Maps icon in the info header section, and below the map are five sections: All, Places Lived, **Trips**, Life Events, and Photos.

Where does the Trips part come from?  I actually would like to fill that part out.  Facebook help has nothing on it that I could find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your Timeline. Click on the `Life Event` tab where the status update box is.

Life Event will give you the following options:

- Work & Education
- Family & Relationships
- Home & Living
- Health & Wellness
- **Travel & Experiences**

Click on `Travel & Experiences` --> `Travel`.

You are ready to chronicle your trips.